# while saving data to database in Firebase via Web App occurs

Tags: javascript, html, firebase, web, firebase-realtime-database

Like if I have these two input boxes.

```
  <input type="button" id="valone">
  <input type="button" id="valuetwo">
  <button type="submit" onClick="submitB();" id="sbmtbtn">
  <script> 
    const firstval = findViewById="valueone";
    const secondval = findViewById="valuetwo";
    const submit = findViewById="sbmtbtn";

    const first = firstval.value;
    const second = secondval.value;

   function submitB() {

    const firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref().push();

    firebaseRef.child("Value").child("Value One").set(first.value);
    firebaseRef.child("Value").child("Value Two").set(second.value);

                }
```

But it does this image like .......

[image: image of database please see]

It shows blanks not the values of the input box

Please help me all dependencies are set upped correctly and everything is pretty fine.

Comment: Is `findViewById` supposed to be a function?

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to look up the HTML elements, but are using a non-existing function. You're looking for `getElementById()`, like this:

```
<input type="button" id="valone">
<input type="button" id="valuetwo">
<button type="submit" onClick="submitB();" id="sbmtbtn">
<script> 
const firstElm = findElementById("valueone");
const secondElm = findElementById("valuetwo");
const submitBtn = findElementById("sbmtbtn");

const first = firstElm.value;
const second = secondElm.value;

function submitB() {
  const firebaseRef = firebase.database().ref().push();

  firebaseRef.child("Value").child("Value One").set(first);
  firebaseRef.child("Value").child("Value Two").set(second);
}
```